# WhatsApp running in background

Tags: windows-10-mobile, whatsapp, background-tasks, nokia-lumia-1320, push-notifications

I am using Lumia 1320 which has windows-10 OS installed on it.I want to receive WhatsApp notification only when i open that application .

So from 'Background Apps' settings option, i have disabled background app option for WhatsApp. But still when i connect to internet, i get WhatsApp notifications.

This is also happening when battery saver is on.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
Thanks